# Using active cell value in userform label

Tags: excel, label, userform

I open a userform when double-clicking on a cell;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Range("B5:K20"), Target) Is Nothing Then

    Cancel = True
    UserForm1.Show

    End If

End Sub
```

I would like to add the cell value from the cell I double clicked to Label1 on the userform.

I tried `UserForm1.Label1.Caption = ActiveCell.Value` after `UserForm1.Show`. On the first double click, the userform shows no value in Label1, the second time I double click a cell, Label1 shows the cell value of the first cell I double clicked.

How can I show the current (double-clicked) cell value when the userform opens?

Comment: You will have to create a `Property` in the userform that you can `Set` the value from the double-clicked cell. Then you'll use that property value to the `.Caption` of a label or the `.Text` of a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible tell excel that the label is = to teh taget before showing the form.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim s As String
    If Not Intersect(Range("B5:K20"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        s = Target.Value

        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = s
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```